# How can test component rendering JSX element only when boolean flag is true

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Suppose I have the following component that I would like to test:

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
      >
        Show Modal
      </button>
      { isOpen ? <Modal>...</Modal> : <div>No Modal</div>}
    </>
  )
}
```

Now I would like to have the component rendering the Modal component in its initial rendering and test its DOM. How can I pass `showModal = true` to it?

```
discribe("Rendered TestComponent", () => {
  it("has Modal component", () => {
    // Some operation needed here or after rendering the component?
    render(<TestComponent />);
    expect(screen.getByRole('input', {name: 'first-name' }).toBeInTheDocument;
  })
})
```

Comment: You do it the same way you'd do it as a user in a browser, you click the button. See the quickstart: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro

Answer (score -1):

First you have to attribute a `data-testid` to the button tag in order to manipulate it, keep the ID unique throughout the whole application.

Then you can use your favorite test lib to fire a click event, there are many avaliable that can do events, such as fire event:

```js
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        data-testid="show-modal"
        onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
      >
        Show Modal
      </button>
      { showModal ? <Modal>...</Modal> : <div>No Modal</div>}
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
describe("Rendered TestComponent", () => {
  it("has Modal component", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<TestComponent />);
    const showModalButton = getByTestId("show-modal");
    fireEvent.click(showModalButton);
    expect(screen.getByRole('input', { name: 'first-name' })).toBeInTheDocument;
  });
});
```